# time shift between target and simulation output using neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network, offset, lag, prediction

I'm currently working with neural networks and I'm still beginner. My purpose is to use a MLP to predict flow time series (I know, that NARX-networks may be more suitable for time series predictions, but the requirement is a MLP).

For example I want to predict the flow `Q(t+x)` with current and historical flow `Q(t...t-n)` and precipitation `P(t...t-m)` etc.

The results of my net-trainings (training, validation and test of the network) and an additional validation period show relatively good qualities (correlation and RMSE). But when I look closer at the output of training and validation period, there is a lag to the targets of the respective periode. And my problem is that I don't know why.

The lag exactly corresponds to my forecast period x, no matter how large x is.

I use a standard MLP from the Matlab-toolbox with default Settings (randomly divide, trainlm, etc.) like using the graphical NN-tool (but I also tested other Settings with my own code).

With a simple `Q(t)` NAR-net it is the same problem. If I try it with regular data like predicting `sin(t+x)` with `sin(t..t-n)` or the same with a rectangular function there is no time shift, it's all fine.

Only if I use real world data or irregular (but most constant) data like `[0.12 0.14 0.13 0.1 0.1 0.1 ...` (n times) `0.1 ... 0.1 0.1 0.14 0.15 0.12 ...]` there is the shift between the target and the output. Although I train the network with the target `Q(t+x)` the real training output is `Q(t)`. I try also some other input variable combinations from less to more information. My time series is above 7 years with hourly resolution. But it also occurs with other resolutions.

Is there something I am wrong in my work or something I can try. I've read that some others also have this Problem, but no solutions? I think it is no failure of my implementation, because I also tried the matlab-tool and the sinus function and there are the same outcomes. And if I ignore the shift, the accuracy of the values is not bad (thats why the goodness of correlation and rmse is also good obviously).

I use matlab 2012.

Here's also a minimalistic code example, only with the most import points. But also shows the problem very well.

```
%% minimalstic example
% but there is the same problem with more input variables

load Q

%% create net inputs and targets

% start point of t
t = 100; 

% history data of Q -> Q(t-1), Q(t-2), Q(t-3)
inputs = [Q(t-1:end-1,1) Q(t-2:end-2,1) Q(t-3:end-3,1)]';

% timestep t that want to be predicted
targets = Q(t:end,1)';

%% create fitting net (MLP) 
% but it is the same problem for NARnet
% and from here, you can also use the NN graphical tool

% number of hidden neurons
numHiddenNeurons = 6;  % the described problem is not dependent on this 
                       % point, therefor it is freely chosen

net = fitnet(numHiddenNeurons); % same problem if choosing the old version newfit

% default MLP settings, no changes, but the problem even exist with other
% combinations of settings

% train net
[trained_net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);

% apply trained net with given data (create net outputs)
outputs = sim(trained_net,inputs);

figure(1)
hold on
bar(targets',0.6,'FaceColor','r','EdgeColor','none')
bar(outputs',0.2,'FaceColor','b','EdgeColor','none')
legend('observation','prediction')
% please zoom very far to see single bars!! the bar plot shows very good
% the time shift
% if you choose a bigger forecasting time, the shift will also be better to
% see

%% the result: targets(1,1)=Q(t), outputs(1,1)=Q(t-1)

%% now try the sinus function, the problem will not be there

x = 1:1:1152;
SIN = sin(x);

inputs = [SIN(1,t-1:end-1);SIN(1,t-2:end-2);SIN(1,t-3:end-3)];
targets = SIN(1,t:end);

% start again from above, creating the net
```

I have not enough reputations to upload two excerpts of the results of the codes for one step ahead prediction.

Comment: I am unsure about what exactly you mean by "time shift" (cant test code). Maybe you can add data. However, since it's prediction, you want a time shift from the input to the target data since you're predicting the next n (n=timeframe) steps. It might also explain why sinus "works" - cause it's a periodical function. It's still time-shifted but if timewindow=phase you won't notice it.

Comment: As far as I understand your description, you want to do a single step prediction. Your method works for a sine signal. Using a more complex signal, you observe that the prediction is delayed by exactly one sample. This means that your neural net implements Q(t) = Q(t-1).

In other words, your net does not work as intended because it cannot solve the problem. The best thing it can accomplish is the trivial prediction of sample and hold.

Comment: The @Diphtong comment is true. That is not a delay, that is a prediction uncertainty and the network is only delivering the trivial prediction. Try to show an image of how the `Q` data looks like?. See you soon.

Answer (score 1):

Consider predicting not the absolute value of the flow, but the *change* of flow from the previous period, using the recent changes from the previous periods as inputs. As pointed out by Diphtong above, it very well may be the case that the previous flow values are not predictive of (contain no useful information about) the next flow value.

Conceptually, this is similar to predicting the next value of a [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk). Imagine you had a situation where the next value of a function was equal to the current value plus some random number between -1.0 and +1.0. If you tried to predict the next value from the previous values, the best that any function approximator/regressor could do to minimize the prediction error would be to use the current value as the best predictor of the next value.

However, in your case, it could still be possible that there is *some* information in the previous flow values. To prevent the current value from overwhelming the error term, deny the network from using the current value as the predictor by feeding it the derivative of the absolute flow values. If there is no useful information in those either, it should minimize the error by always predicting 0.

In summary, try:

- Inputs: change in flow at [t-1], at [t-2], ... , [t-w]
- Output: change in flow at [t]

Answer (score 1):

This "time-shift" you are observing is exactly what @Diphtong mentions: your neural-network cannot resolve the relationship between the inputs and the output, so it bahaves like a "naive predictor" (look it up) where (in the financial stock market world) the best prediction for tomorrow's stock price is today's price.

It may help, but I've seen deltas of the input time series, LOG() and SQRT() perform the same...